# Java Application for 32-bit and 64 bit platform

Tags: java, exe, 32bit-64bit

I have a java application (.exe) file i want to distribute this file so that others can use it.

I have a doubt now whether my application will run in windows OS irrespective of bit ( either in 32 or 64 bit ) ? Or do i need any specific files for my application to run in both.

Comment: A Java program doesn't normally result in an .exe file. How did you really produce the .exe file?

Comment: Even if you build your jar as .exe file, you just need to have JRE installed on the computer to run java application  (32 or 64 bits)

Comment: if you are running Win 7 64-bit, or Win Server 2008 R2, you may install 32-bit JRE in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6" and 64-bit JRE in "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"

Comment: I used a external software to make my jar to exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you generate classes and jars/libs for storing/distributing them. You can generate .exe files to run an application, but this isn't a practice I've seen often and usually requires some 3rd party program.

Assuming you have a .exe file generated on a 32 bit machine, it should work without problems on 64. The reverse isn't possible, but I may be mistaken.

One thing that you must be careful is the version of java used for generating your classes. The remote machines should have a similar java version installed. Can be a newer version than the one you used. (Eg. if you used Java 7, it's ok if the target machine uses Java 8)